# How to generate a subscription system that expire after a defined amount of time? Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

Hello my fellow internet companions, I shall need your help once again.

I'm trying to develop a Drupal Website with an user base which pay a different fee upon the kind of subscription.

After a defined span of time, the subscription should expire, unless the user pay again for mantain the access to the services; which module do you suggest me to use for manage these tasks? We're trying to avoid the use of content types because we'd like to use the Drupal Users core system, but it appears almost impossible.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about the ability for users to have different subscriptions to certain services?

First thought: I think a combination of rules and cron will help you out with this?
Still thinking further though.....

Comment: so the Cron should be perform a daily routine which check whether an user has a privilege or not? Is that the idea? It might work, I'll look better for it. Thanks